# Firefox 5 - mousemove doesn't fire outside of iframe

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, dom-events, mouseevent

Firefox 4 and 5 has bug reported that, when user mouse downs in an iframe and moves the mouse around, parent document doesn't fire mousemove/mouseover events. Is there any custom Javascript temporary workaround to this until it is fixed? This works in Chrome and Firefox 3.6.

Bug link: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=644964

Bug sample: http://bananascript.com/mouseover/

Comment: IIRC, they weren't patching FF4 to use it as a reason to migrate to FF5.  Dunno if it's worth being concerned about FF4

Comment: I suspect that the answer is "no". This regression comes from fixes to drag&drop code but drag&drop events don't fire in this scenario either.

Comment: Has anyone found a workaround? This issue is destroying drag and drop functionality for me.